# Mensaje de error un tanto extraño de thread o de playsound

Tags: python, hilos

Buenas tengo el siguiente py:

Sonido.py

```
from playsound import playsound
import threading

class ruido (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,sonido):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sonido = sonido
    #def run (self):
        directorio = 'D:\\S\\Sonidos\\'
        melodia = ''
        if self.sonido == 'bien':
            melodia = directorio + 'mario-bros.mp3'
        if self.sonido == 'mal':
            melodia = directorio + 'pacman-dies.mp3'
        if self.sonido == 'botes-bien':
            melodia = directorio + 'R2D2.mp3'
        if self.sonido == 'aplausos':
            melodia = directorio + 'applause.mp3'
        if self.sonido == 'electro':
            melodia = directorio + 'Electro-shock.mp3'
        if self.sonido == 'fin':
            melodia = directorio + 'Windows Print complete.mp3'
        if self.sonido == 'Error':
            melodia = directorio + 'Windows Error.mp3'
        if self.sonido == 'Comienzo':
            melodia = directorio + 'Comienzo.mp3'
            #melodia = directorio + 'Si tú no vuelves -Mónica Naranjo.mp3'
                        
        if melodia == '':
            print ('Melodia vacia.--------------')
        else:
            ruido = threading.Thread(target=playsound,args=(melodia),name='!Musica¡')
            ruido.start()
            print ('bienbienbien',melodia)
```

en otro lo importo correcciones.py

```
from sonidos import ruido
```

y para usarlo

```
ruido('Comienzo').start()
```

Me ha estado funcionando hasta ayer, y no sé porque razón lanza el siguiente mensaje:

```
Exception in thread !Musica¡:
bienbienbien D:\S\Sonidos\Comienzo.mp3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
Tiempo empleado: 00:00:01
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: _playsoundWin() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 31 were given
```

Lo ejecuto en un entorno virtual que ya he reiniciado, y continua exactamente igual. He probado con pygame, en el programa principal correcciones.py, y no se me reproduce ningún sonido, y si consigo solucionar lo del hilo, tampoco se me reproduce ningún sonido.
En el primer caso, en el Mezclador de Sonidos de Windows 10, durante una fracción de segundo me parece que sale el logo de python, pero no llego a "pillarlo".

La versión del playsound es la 1.2.2

Supongo que es un error un tanto 'único' pero no sé que más hacer.

Gracias anticipadas.

Agradezco el tiempo dedicado. He eliminado el Thread y dejado solo el playsound para continuar con el desarrollo, cuando retome esta parte del código volveré a postear mi problema, si me surge. Gracias. Pueden dar por cerrada esta pregunta.

Comment: No veo claro qué significa el error con el código que muestras. ¿Dónde se calcula el tiempo empleado?¿De dónde salen los 31 argumentos pasados a playsound? ¿Falta código? Por si no te has fijado, estás creando dos hilos. Uno al invocar el método `__init__` de la superclase y otro al invocar `threading.Thread()` al final del `__init__`. Este último es quien invoca a playsound y termina sin esperar a que termine la ejecución del hilo que ha lanzado, por lo que no escucharás nada. Añade un `ruido.join()` a ver si por lo menos se escucha algo.

Comment: El error es que no se me reproduce ningun sonido y desconozco si es por el thread o por el playsound. A estas horas y haciendo pruebas, aunque me faltan algunas, creo que es producido por el thread. Los 31 argumentos del playsound, no sé de donde los saca, el código es el que muestro. Gracias por lo del __init__ y el join, lo añadire a mis pruebas.

Comment: Como te digo, lo más seguro es que no se reproduzca ningún sonido porque te cargas el hilo enseguida. No necesitas derivar de `threading.Thread`. Intenta hacer las pruebas sin crear ninguna clase, sólo con funciones.

Answer (score 0):

El error puntual está ocurriendo en el argumento args:

```
threading.Thread(target=playsound,args=(melodia),name='!Musica¡')
```

(melodia) no crea una tupla como piensas, si no que actúa como parentesis normales. O sea, es equivalente a args=melodia.

Los 31 argumentos son cada caracter del directorio del sonido pasado en forma de argumento a playsound.

Para indicarle a Python que querés armar una tupla, hay que poner una coma antes del cierre de parentesis: `args=(melodia,)`. Es una locura como en programación un solo caracter puede cambiarlo todo.

Sin embargo, ten en cuenta dos cosas, que ya te han señalado, sobre tu código:

- Estás creando dos tareas distintas. Una en forma de subclase y otra en el init. Es más conveniente usar una subclase o trabajar directo con threading.Thread. Pero no ambos.
- Como la tarea no bloquea el programa y suele terminar cuando termina dicho, no llegaría a sonar el sonido y tu programa finalizaría. Para probar el sonido, podrías hacer un input que trabe el programa hasta que des enter. O usar latarea.join para unir la tarea con la tarea principal.

Comment: Gracias. Ya he realizado los cambios que me indicas y el error continua.

Comment: Gracias. Ya he realizado los cambios que me indicas y el error continua. "TypeError: _playsoundWin() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 33 were given". Corregí lo de la coma, quite el class y lo deje solo con def ruido. Lo de trabajar directo con threading.Thread, no lo entiendo muy bien. También he colocado un join después del start, con el mismo resultado

Comment: @Jose Lo mejor que puedes hacer es añadir a la pregunta estos cambios que has hecho.